# Is it possible to use Picasso/OkHttp3Downloader to save images directly instead of .1 files?

Tags: android, okhttp, picasso

I'm using Picasso in an Android app to download images from remote URLs, and I see them being saved as .0 and .1 files in the device's storage. I need to be able to share these images with another package/app on the device by sending the image file locations. I know that changing the ".1" to a ".jpg" (for example) before I save the file will allow me to view the image, but I was wondering if there is a way to save these files as ".jpg" or ".png" files to begin with, instead of re-saving the images after they have been downloaded. (Out of curiosity, why are the responses saved as .1 files? Edit with answer: The .0 and .1 files are a feature of the OkHttp cache; see [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-analyze-cache-files) for more details.)

Here's how I've initialized Picasso within my app:

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
builder.memoryCache(new LruCache(context));
builder.downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(context));
picasso = builder.build();
```

Comment: So the .1 files will be files internal to the cache structure adn not things you should be accessing directly.  Likely a solution like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066637/android-picasso-save-image-locally-before-viewing-it-in-imageview?rq=1 would be a more correct way to access the files.